# Get current logged in username from Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-applications, active-directory, audit

My web application uses Active Directory Authentication when a user logs in. I use the following code for audit columns. It works perfectly fine for the CreatedAt and ModifiedAt dates but the currentUsername is hardcoded.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseClass && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        var currentUsername = "T";
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseClass)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                ((BaseClass)entity.Entity).CreatedBy = currentUsername;
            }
            ((BaseClass)entity.Entity).ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
            ((BaseClass)entity.Entity).ModifiedBy = currentUsername;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

How can I get the current username logged in Active Directory?

Comment: You'll need to give some info about how exactly you are authenticating against Active Directory as there would be numerous possible ways that you would identify the current user.     If you are using Windows authentication then HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity may get you what you want, however if you are using Microsoft IdentityModel or some other managed authentication process then there would be different ways to capture the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4.5 or higher, just use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and the `UserPrincipal` class in that context:

```
// you'll need to add a reference to this .NET assembly in your project
// so that you can use this namespace
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public string GetLoggedInUser()
{
    // establish the PrincipalContext - this will grab the default domain, default containers
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
         // get the currently active user
         UserPrincipal currentUser = UserPrincipal.Current;

         if (currentUser != null)
         {
             // this will return "first name last name" separated by a space,
             // e.g. "John Doe" or "Jane Tarzan" 
             return $"{currentUser.GivenName} {currentUser.Surname}";
         }
    }

    return string.Empty;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for getting the logged in username of the remote-session but not the user who has logged in to the web application

Comment: @Techy: getting the user in the web app would *only* work if the web app is hosted with **Windows authentication** enabled (in e.g. IIS). Otherwise, your users will be "anonymous"

Comment: Note that code won't compile because you're not returning anything if `currentUser == null`. Also, you don't need to create the `PrincipalContext` in that code. It's not used. (doesn't hurt, but doesn't help)